# Rename the user field on FacebookUser with Spring Security Facebook Grails Plugin

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

I'm using the Spring Security Facebook Plugin with Grails 3, and my Spring Security user domain class is call `Person`.  The [documentation](http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/#example-app) instruct us to create the FacebookUser domain class like with a belongs to relationship to the User class...

from plugin docs:

```
class FacebookUser {
  ...    
  static belongsTo = [user: User] //connected to main Spring Security domain
  ...    
  }
}
```

I want to know if I can do this...

```
  static belongsTo = [person: Person]
```

or do I have to do this...

```
  static belongsTo = [user: Person]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer here: http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/#configure-domains.  You just need to configure `appUserConnectionPropertyName` like this...

```
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            facebook:
                domain:
                    classname: 'co.sharptop.app.FacebookUser'
                    appUserConnectionPropertyName: 'person'
```